Problems installing tensor flow on my laptop
I currently trying to install tensorflow-gpu on my laptop with WSL, for windows 11, and after following the steps in tensorflow official page, my device is not founding the GPU. Anybody knows the solution to this problem?
enter image description here
I follow the steps found here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2_1
Also tried several YouTube videos, but the step seems to be very different the installation for previous versions.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi @Matias Toth ,
To fix this problem, you need to make sure that you have installed the required GPU libraries, such as the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN library, correctly on your system. And also make sure that your GPU drivers are up to date.
